# Largest Cube that fits the space between two Spheres?

Tags: geometry, contest-math, 3d

Two spheres, one of radius 15 and the other of radius 33, have the same center. Find the side length of the largest cube that fits between them.

Comment: Two answers; one if the cube is a wire frame, so that four vertices lie on each sphere. Different answer if the cube is solid, so the center of one square rests on the 15 sphere, while four vertices lie on the 33 sphere.

Comment: @samjoe yes. I have drawn a plane that passes through two diagonally opposite points on the top square of the cube.

Comment: @will you are correct, my mind was fixed in $2D$ :)

Comment: @Will For wire frame case, I dont think four vertices will lie on 15 sphere. Only other four will lie on 33 sphere. This case is much much harder to handle (atleast for me)

Comment: @samjoe yes, if we think of them as actual wires, the midpoint of a wire in the lower square would lie on the 15 sphere; I don't see that any single plane drawing would give all information in this case. So there are actually three, fairly reasonable, interpretations of the problem. The least realistic is just to have all vertices lie on the spheres.

Comment: @samjoe, the wire frame case gives $41 S^4 - 48960 S^2 + 11943936 = 0.$ I got this by squaring a square root, so the larger positive root is fake; the actual figure is the smaller one, just a bit larger than my answer below, that is $S \approx 18.48696,$ where the answer for a solid cube is $S = 16.$

Comment: I considered the same way. Narrow gap betw. square base and outer circle $ =(18-a)$. Half base diagnol =$a/\sqrt2$;  $ (a/\sqrt2)^2 = (18-a) ( 66- 18+a) $ Simplify $ a^2+20 a -576 =0 , \rightarrow a = (16,-36) $ latter soln. is spuroius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tuesday:  the wire frame case gives $41 S^4 - 48960 S^2 + 11943936 = 0.$ I got this by squaring a square root, so the larger positive root is fake; the actual figure is the smaller one, just a bit larger than my answer below, that is $S \approx 18.48696.$

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

In order to get everything in a single plane, we must rotate by 45 degrees...

I got $S^2 + 20 S - 576 = 0, $ or $(S + 36)(S - 16) = 0.$

So $S=16.$ Give me a few minutes, I will give coordinates for the vertices of the cube...

The bottom square of the cube has vertices $(8,8,15), (8,-8,15),(-8,8,15), (-8,-8,15).$ The top square has vertices $(8,8,31), (8,-8,31),(-8,8,31), (-8,-8,31).$

We get confirmation that it all works from 
$$  8^2 + 8^2 + 31^2 = 33^2, $$
sometimes called a Pythagorean Quadruple.

[image]

Comment: After I posted my solution I saw you have edited yours.

Answer (score 1):

After $Will$ solved the side length of the solid cube, here is my solution to the wire frame cube. The midpoints of the four sides of a square would lie on the 15 sphere and the four vertices of the opposite square of the cube would lie on the 33 sphere.
[image]

Comment: good diagram...

Comment: Nice solution.. I also used same approach, but how did you solve them

Comment: @samjoe, just solved them numerically.